# dialog partially hidden

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Inside some Activity I have Button, which opens Dialog (marked as Fragment on pic).

In this Dialog I have some other Button and EditText.
By default, focus set to EditText.
[image: Device screen]

The problem is, when the Dialog is opened, it's not shown completely. The Button is hidden behind the screen (Screen and Hidden sections on pic), so I have to scroll up to see the Button.

I've tried to disable EditText focus, tried to set focus to Button, but Dialog is still not fully shown.

Is there any way I can force the Dialog to open completely?

It appears, that the Dialog covers exactly half of the Screen. If I don't have a lot of elements inside, it shown completely, if I do - I have to scroll.

**UPD:**
My Dialog uses custom XML with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="300dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/someid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="270dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:visibility="visible">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/editTextLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:visibility="visible">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/EditText"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/overlayButtons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white_70"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="gone" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

P.S. the structure is complex, because I have a lot of other elements like Buttons, Text etc. inside. I've deleted them and left only important one like Linear/Relative layouts.

Comment: Does your dialog use a custom xml layout?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: @HaroldHibari yes, I use custom XML.

Comment: @ElMaravilla I've posted the code.

Comment: Change the First LinearLayout's height from "wrap_content" to "match_parent" and tell me if that fixes it

Comment: @HaroldHibari, changed. Still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've figured it out.

It's impossible to define dialog`s height via layout, so I had to do it in the code.

Here is code snippet:

```
   DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    int maxHeight = (int) (height*0.75);
    final BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) view.getParent());
    bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(maxHeight);
```

So now, dialog can occupy up to 75% of screen height if needed.